# Calling an Oracle stored procedure in PHP - ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm trying to call a stored procedure in Oracle but get the following error:

> ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Here's my PHP code:

```
$cur = oci_new_cursor($connApp);

$sql = 'BEGIN ICT_FORMS.P_FORM1(
    :in_action,
    :in_form1_urn,
    :in_cby,
    :in_created_dt,
    :in_dept_code,
    :in_post_code,
    :in_budget_code,
    :in_reason_req,
    :in_oh_adj,
    :in_outcome_urn,
    :in_serv1,
    :in_serv2,
    :in_serv3,
    :in_serv4,
    :in_group_urn,
    :in_sup_staffno,
    :out_err,
    :out_cursor,
    :out_cursor2,
    :out_cursor3,
    :out_newurn);
    END;';

$stmt = oci_parse($connApp, $sql);

$action = 'MYA';
$staffno = '245578';
$null = null;
$zero = 0;

// bind the input parameters
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':in_action', $action);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':in_cby', $staffno);

// bind the cursor
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,":out_cursor", $cur,-1, OCI_B_CURSOR);

// bind all of the null variables
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':in_form1_urn', $zero);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':in_created_dt', $null);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':in_dept_code', $null);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':in_post_code', $null);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':in_budget_code', $null);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':in_reason_req', $null);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':in_oh_adj', $null);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':in_outcome_urn', $zero);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':in_serv1', $null);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':in_serv2', $null);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':in_serv3', $null);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':in_serv4', $null);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':in_group_urn', $zero);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':in_sup_staffno', $zero);

oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':out_err', $error);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':out_cursor2', $cur2, -1, OCI_B_CURSOR);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':out_cursor3', $cur3, -1, OCI_B_CURSOR);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ':out_newurn', $newURN);

oci_execute($stmt);
oci_execute($cur);

while($row = oci_fetch_assoc($cur))
{
    var_dump($row);
}
```

And here's the stored procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE           P_FORM1 (
    in_action       IN VARCHAR2,
    in_form1_urn        IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
    in_cby              IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    in_created_dt       IN DATE DEFAULT NULL,
    in_dept_code        IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    in_post_code        IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    in_budget_code      IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    in_reason_req       IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    in_oh_adj           IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    in_outcome_urn      IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
    in_serv1            IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'N',
    in_serv2            IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'N',
    in_serv3            IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'N',
    in_serv4            IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'N',

    in_group_urn        IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0,
    in_sup_staffno      IN NUMBER DEFAULT 0,

    out_err             OUT VARCHAR2,
    out_cursor          OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
    out_cursor2             OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
    out_cursor3         OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
    out_newurn          OUT NUMBER
) as 

f1_new_urn NUMBER := 0;

comm_new_urn NUMBER := 0;

cursor NEW_Form1_CURSOR is
select ICT_Forms.s_form_1_seq.nextval from dual;


cursor NEW_Form1_comments_CURSOR is
select ICT_Forms.s_form_1_comments_seq.nextval from dual;


/* --------- Local Variables --------- */
sql_statement VARCHAR2(4000) :=null;

sql_statement2 VARCHAR2(4000) :=null;

sql_statement3 VARCHAR2(4000) :=null;



-- View Attributes [inc foreign key descriptions]
        view1_name VARCHAR2(4000) := ' ICT_Forms.v_Form_list T1 ';

    view1_cols VARCHAR2(4000) := ' urn, date_created, Form_name, outcome, cby ' ;

        view2_name VARCHAR2(4000) := ' ICT_Forms.v_Form1_auth_list T1 ';

    view2_cols VARCHAR2(4000) := ' urn, date_created, created_by, form_name, outcome, supervisor_name, sup_staffno ' ;

    view3_name VARCHAR2(4000) := ' ICT_Forms.v_form1';

    view3_cols VARCHAR2(4000) := ' urn, Date_created, form_name ,department_lpa, Department_name, Description, budget_code, Reason_req, Oh_adj, outcome' ;

    view4_name VARCHAR2(4000) := ' ICT_Forms.v_form1_serv';

    view4_cols VARCHAR2(4000) := ' service_type, service_desc, cost' ;

    view5_name VARCHAR2(4000) := ' ICT_Forms.v_form1_comments';

    view5_cols VARCHAR2(4000) := ' Comments_by ,comments_date, auth_type, Comments, Group_name' ;


/* --------- Main Processing Block --------- */

BEGIN

out_err := '0';

-- ******************************************************************************************************************   
IF in_action = 'MYA' then  -- Select List of Form1 by staff_no

sql_statement := 'SELECT' ||  view1_cols || ' FROM ' ||  view1_name ||
                  'WHERE Cby =:in_cby';

        OPEN out_cursor FOR sql_statement using in_cby;

--
******************************************************************************************************************  


ELSE

    out_err := '[P_FORM1] Action not valid: ' || in_action;

END IF;

-- ******************************************************************************************************************   


EXCEPTION

  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    out_err := '[P_FORM1] An error has occurred - '||SQLCODE||' - ERROR - '||SQLERRM || chr(10) ||
                   'SQL Statement: ' || sql_statement ;


END;
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong please? I have checked that all 21 parameters in the PHP match the 21 parameters in the procedure and they do, and they all seem to be bound correctly.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out with the help of a colleague, it turns out that even though I had planned on using a single cursor, all 3 had to be declared and executed using `oci_new_cursor` and then `oci_execute`:

```
$cur = oci_new_cursor($connApp);
$cur2 = oci_new_cursor($connApp);
$cur3 = oci_new_cursor($connApp);

oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":out_cursor", $cur,-1, SQLT_RSET);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":out_cursor2", $cur2, -1, SQLT_RSET);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":out_cursor3", $cur3, -1, SQLT_RSET);

oci_execute($stmt);
oci_execute($cur);
oci_execute($cur2);
oci_execute($cur3);
```